# Cocoapods - target overrides the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

### PROBLEM:

You run `pod install` and get the following error

```
The 'XXX [Debug]' target overrides the 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' build setting defined in 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXX/Pods-XXX.debug.xcconfig'. 
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the '$(inherited)' flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

- You try deleting all of the rows in Library Search Paths and still get the error.
- You try adding `$(inherited)` as the first item. Cocoapods stops complaining, but you no longer see all of the search paths that were originally imported.

Answer (score 14):

Watch the 2 min video here: https://youtu.be/XvaqW0lQL18

1. Go to Library Search Paths in XCode's Build Settings for your target
2. Double click, select any entries in there and click the '-' button to delete them.

   You'll notice that the field is now empty BUT the "Library Search Paths" is now bold.
3. Select the bold "Library Search Paths" row and hit Backspace

You should see all of the original search paths magically reappear.

I can't believe how unintuitive this is.

Comment: Correct answer. Curse to the one who designed the stuff in such a bad manner